# Error in Tic Tac Toe game, but no error output

Tags: python

I have created a basic tic tac toe game and everything seems to work except for checking most of the X win situations. O works fine for all cases, but X does not. I don't understand what is wrong.

I have tried to combine the win conditions into one group, and that did not work. I don't see any errors.

```
def def_board():
  global board
  empty = "| |"
  board = {'1':empty, '2':empty, '3':empty, '4':empty, '5':empty, '6':empty, '7':empty, '8':empty, '9':empty,}
  print("Board:")
  print('|1|2|3|\n|4|5|6|\n|7|8|9|')

def board_check_x():
  board_check_board = ["null", board['1'], board['2'], board['3'] ,board['4'],board['5'],board['6'],board['7'],board['8'],board['9']]
  if "|X|" == board_check_board[1] and "|X|" == board_check_board[2] and "|X|" == board_check_board[3]:
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[4] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[6]):
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[7] and "|X|" == board_check_board[8] and "|X|" == board_check_board[9]):
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[1] and "|X|" == board_check_board[4] and "|X|" == board_check_board[7]):
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[2] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[8]):
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[3] and "|X|" == board_check_board[6] and "|X|" == board_check_board[9]):
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[1] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[9]):
    player_win("2")
  if "|X|" == (board_check_board[3] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[7]):
    player_win("2")

def board_check_o():
  board_check_board = ["null", board['1'], board['2'], board['3'] ,board['4'],board['5'],board['6'],board['7'],board['8'],board['9']]
  if "|O|" == board_check_board[1] and "|O|" == board_check_board[2] and "|O|" == board_check_board[3]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[4] and "|O|" == board_check_board[5] and "|O|" == board_check_board[6]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[7] and "|O|" == board_check_board[8] and "|O|" == board_check_board[9]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[1] and "|O|" == board_check_board[4] and "|O|" == board_check_board[7]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[2] and "|O|" == board_check_board[5] and "|O|" == board_check_board[8]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[3] and "|O|" == board_check_board[6] and "|O|" == board_check_board[9]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[1] and "|O|" == board_check_board[5] and "|O|" == board_check_board[9]:
    player_win("1")
  elif "|O|" == board_check_board[3] and "|O|" == board_check_board[5] and "|O|" == board_check_board[7]:
    player_win("1")
```

I want the game to check to see if you get X three times in a row. The game instead does not register it for the X case, but works fine for O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `board_check_x` function.

Try this:

```
def board_check_x():
  board_check_board = ["null", board['1'], board['2'], board['3'] ,board['4'],board['5'],board['6'],board['7'],board['8'],board['9']]
  if "|X|" == board_check_board[1] and "|X|" == board_check_board[2] and "|X|" == board_check_board[3]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[4] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[6]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[7] and "|X|" == board_check_board[8] and "|X|" == board_check_board[9]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[1] and "|X|" == board_check_board[4] and "|X|" == board_check_board[7]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[2] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[8]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[3] and "|X|" == board_check_board[6] and "|X|" == board_check_board[9]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[1] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[9]:
    player_win("2")
  elif "|X|" == board_check_board[3] and "|X|" == board_check_board[5] and "|X|" == board_check_board[7]:
    player_win("2")
```

If your o works, this should work for x. I just refactored your o function to look for x with two quick regex's in my editor.